# Specifying Default Windows Version for Wine in a Docker Container

Tags: software-installation, python, wine, docker, winetricks

I would like to build windows binaries from my python project using [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) via [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). I am using [**engineervix/pyinstaller-windows**](https://hub.docker.com/r/engineervix/pyinstaller-windows), which I forked from [**cdrx/pyinstaller-windows**](https://hub.docker.com/r/cdrx/pyinstaller-windows) to use more recent Ubuntu LTS images (18.04/20.04), and newer Python releases and other software.

In the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/engineervix/docker-pyinstaller/blob/py3-win64/Dockerfile), I have `winetricks -q win10`, and the build logs seem to indicate that this was successful:

```
...
...

------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20200412-next - sha256sum: 6f57ead2f28148ef7d801b1c0dbf10cf327d22b2fcbe0f742dd1579097f66635 with wine-5.0.2 and WINEARCH=win64
Executing w_do_call win10
Executing mkdir -p /
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing load_win10
The operation completed successfully
Setting Windows version to win10
Executing wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\set-winver.reg
Executing wine64 regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\set-winver.reg
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/wine terminate
------------------------------------------------------

...
...

[91m+ echo assoc .py=PythonScript
[0m
Microsoft Windows 10.0.10240
C:\Python37>
.py
=
PythonScript
C:\Python37>
[91m+ [0m
[91mwine[0m
[91m cmd[0m
[91m
[0m
[91m+ [0m
[91mecho[0m
[91m ftype PythonScript=c:\Python37\python.exe "%1" %*[0m
[91m
[0m
Microsoft Windows 10.0.10240
C:\Python37>
PythonScript
=
c:\Python37\python.exe "%1" %*
C:\Python37>

...
...
```

However, when using the Docker Image, I get the following from the PyInstaller logs:

```
...
...

pyinstaller --clean -F --windowed --upx-dir=upx build_win.spec
170 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
170 INFO: Python: 3.7.9
171 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601
335 INFO: UPX is available.
336 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\users\root\Application Data\pyinstaller
365 INFO: checking Tree
366 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
366 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
368 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths

...
...
```

From the [`winetricks`](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks) source code, I saw that the default Windows version for Wine is Windows 7. This means that somehow, setting the Windows version with `winetricks -q win10` didn't work, or at least the Windows version was not "persisted" in the Docker container. **What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?** I know that [`winecfg`](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winecfg) can be used to [modify the default version of windows](https://superuser.com/a/398180/159975), but it appears to be a graphical utility, as indicated on the [official site](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winecfg):

> Winecfg is a GUI configuration tool for Wine, designed to make life a little easier than editing the registry.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Phineas I didn't! Do you have the solution? 

Comment: unfortunately I didn't. luckily my app runs in windows 7 as well :p

Answer (score 1):

When doing anything with wine in docker it is safer to wait for the wineserver to finish. wineserver is started in the background and it coordinates things like flushing data to the repository but finishes *after* the main command.

```
RUN winecfg -v win10 && wineserver -w
```